# What's the common API for both `Vec<String>` and flatbuffers' vector of String in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, flatbuffers

I'd like to be able to iterate over Rust vector of String (`Vec<String>`) and [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)' vector of strings: IDL as follows:

```
table Sitekeys {
  domains: [string];
}
```

Here is how the file is generated (with `flatc --rust ...`):

```
  #[inline]
  pub fn domains(&self) -> Option<flatbuffers::Vector<'a, flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<&'a str>>> {
    ...
  }
```

I can't figure the signature of the function that can accept both vectors. I believe it should be the most base possible interface (`trait` in Rust). Coming from J2EE/Android i think about smth similar to `java.util.List` or `java.util.Iterator`.

What would be the suitable signature in Rust?

PS. Obviously i can extract some new common interface with adapter for each case, but i'd prefer to operate with just base interface.

PPS. I forgot to mention that performance matters, so i'd prefer to avoid creating of new instances (if it's used behind the scenes in `into_iter()` or smth) if possible.

Comment: You could accept a slice, `&[String]`. Or perhaps `impl IntoIterator<Item = String>`.

Comment: could you please provide a code snippet for the function that accepts both `fn process(domains: ... /* what here? */)` and call example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flatbuffers::Vector`](https://docs.rs/flatbuffers/0.8.3/flatbuffers/struct.Vector.html) does not implement [`AsRef<[T]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-AsRef%3C%5BT%5D%3E) but it does implement [`IntoIterator`](https://docs.rs/flatbuffers/0.8.3/flatbuffers/struct.Vector.html#impl-IntoIterator), so you can make your function signature use that.

```rust
fn take_iterator<'a>(iter: impl IntoIterator<Item=&'a str>) {}
```

Also, your flatbuffer object actually uses `&str` not `String`, you can match both and use a `Vec<&str>`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let flatbuffer_v: flatbuffers::Vector<flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<&str>> = flatbuffers::Vector::default();
    let std_v: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    take_iterator(flatbuffer_v);
    take_iterator(std_v);
}
```

or, if you have a `Vec<String>` just take the references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let flatbuffer_v: flatbuffers::Vector<flatbuffers::ForwardsUOffset<&str>> = flatbuffers::Vector::default();
    let std_v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    take_iterator(flatbuffer_v);
    take_iterator(std_v.iter().map(AsRef::as_ref));
}
```